# Reading the "IsExpanded" property from the ItemSource of a TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

So I want the IsExpanded Property of the TreeView Item so be reflected in the datacontext.

```
        <TreeView x:Name="TreeViewMonitorEvents" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}, Path=MonitorEventCatagories}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tree:TreeGroup}" ItemsSource="{Binding Members}" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" MouseMove="DragDrop_MouseMove_TreeGroup">
                    <CheckBox Name="CheckboxTreeGroup" IsChecked="{Binding Path=(tree:TreeItemHelper.IsChecked), Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          Template="{DynamicResource MonitoringUICheckBox}" Style="{StaticResource MonitoringUICheckBoxStyling}"
                              MouseMove="DragDrop_MouseMove_TreeGroup" Checked="CheckboxTreeGroup_Checked" Unchecked="CheckboxTreeGroup_Unchecked">
                    </CheckBox>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource MonitorUIText}" MouseMove="DragDrop_MouseMove_TreeGroup"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"  >
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </Style>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I.e the TreeGroup Class.  See Treegroup here:

```
namespace RTX64MonitorUtility.TreeView
{
    //Data class.  Holds information in the Datacontext section of the UI Elements it is attached to.
    public class TreeGroup : DependencyObject, IParent<object>
    {


        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<TreeMonitoringEvent> Members { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<object> GetChildren()
        {
            return Members;
        }

        public bool IsExpanded { get; set; } = false;
    }
}
```

Here is the List it's drawing from:

```
namespace RTX64MonitorUtility.Pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for EventsAndTriggers.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class EventsAndTriggers : Page
    {
         public ObservableCollection<TreeGroup> MonitorEventCatagories { get; set; }
         ...
    }
}
```

My primary goal here is that if the TreeGroup Item is not expanded then the chidren's `Checked` and `Unchecked` events do not get triggered so I need to do the required actions for them.  If I can find out a way of reading the `IsExpanded` value from those events that would also be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually bind the item container's properties like `TreeViewItem.IsExpanded` or `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` etc. to your data model by using a `Style` that targets the item container. The `DataContext` of the item container is the data model:

```xml
<TreeView>
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
      <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Next, implement the data model properly. The properties that are the source of the data binding must be implemented as dependency properties (for dependency objects) or raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event.

Since `DependencyObject` extends `DispatcherObject`, any class that extends DependencyObject is thread affine: in WPF, a `DispatcherObject` can only be accessed by the Dispatcher it is associated with.
For this reason you usually prefer `INotifyPropertyChanged` on data models.
`DependencyObject` is for UI objects that are bound to the `Dispatcher` thread by definition.

```cs
// Let the model implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface
public class TreeGroup : INotifyPropertyChanged, IParent<object>
{
  // Follow this pattern for all properties that will change 
  // and are source of a data binding.
  private bool isExpanded;
  public IsExpanded 
  { 
    get => this.isExpanded; 
    set; 
    {
      this.isExpanded = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

See [Microsoft Docs: Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Comment: adding the above does not affect the property, `IsExpanded` in TreeGroup.  In neither mine or your XAML example the property does not link up.  The DataContext seems to only apply when inside the  `<HierarchicalDataTemplate>`

Comment: Thank you so much for adding the fact that I needed to add the INotifyPropertyChanged resource.  It is sometimes unclear when this Interface is needed.

Comment: This interface is ALWAYS needed when the class is the data source of a data binding where `Binding.Mode`  **is not** `BindingMode.OneWayToSource` or `BindingMode.OneTime` AND if this source is not a `DependencyObject`. When `Binding.Mode`  is either `BindingMode.OneWayToSource` or `BindingMode.OneTime`  and the properties won't change their values, then you can omit the interface. If the source is a `DependencyObject`, always implement the properties as dependency properties. Only classes that are part of the UI should inherit `DependencyObject`. The link provided in my answer explains this.

Comment: To keep it simple, always implement this interface on non DependencyObjects, even if data won't change.

Comment: So these objects could easily be `DependencyObjects` I in fact have them has dependency objects at the bottom level to handle the check state of parent and child.  if I were to make them dependency objects how would I register the "isExpanded" property since it is not part of my template?  I'm worried that having both Inotify and Dependency implemented on the same `treeview` I am causing some performance degradation

Comment: No, these objects are data models and not UI objects. As I was trying to explain, you only let UI objects extend `DependencyObject`. `DependencyObject` inherits from `DispatcherObject` and has thread affinity. You can't access it from different threads. Since WPF uses the STA threading model, UI elements should only associate with the UI thread by design. Data models on the other hand often depend on multithreading. `DependencyObject` is only for UI objects like controls. Your data model should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.